# $\ell_{p}$ spaces with pointwise multiplication

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the $\ell_{p}$ spaces Banach algebras if multiplication is defined pointwise; that is, $(a_{n})(b_{n})=(a_{n}b_{n})$?

Comment: Can you ensure that $\forall a, b\in\ell_p$ $\Rightarrow$ $a\cdot b\in\ell_p$?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Prove that $\Vert a\Vert_{\ell_\infty}\leq\Vert a\Vert_{\ell_p}$ and $a\in\ell_p\implies a\in\ell_\infty$.
2. Show that $\Vert ab\Vert_{\ell_p}\leq\Vert a\Vert_{\ell_\infty}\Vert b\Vert_{\ell_p}$

Comment: Then it is Banach algebra?

Comment: yes $\phantom{}$